# union of contour in java

Tags: java, opencv

Is there an efficient way in opencv/java to compute the union of contour and to get the resulting contour ?

I have tried with conversion of `opencv.contour` to `java.awt.geom.Area` , with `Core.bitwise_` and, to merge `MatOfPoint` to curve and `approxPolyDP`, but nothing give the good result.

Is the only way, to use `drawContour` for contour1 and contour2 on black image, and then to `findContour` ?

Comment: Can you attach sample input images for the two contours?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This forum is meant to help with coding problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is :

```
MatOfPoint contoursIntersection( Mat ref, MatOfPoint cnt1, MatOfPoint cnt2) {

        MatOfPoint intersec = new MatOfPoint();

        Mat blackImage = new Mat();
        ref.copyTo( blackImage);
        blackImage.setTo( new Scalar( 0, 0, 0));

        List<MatOfPoint> coll = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        coll.add(cnt1);
        coll.add(cnt2);
        Imgproc.drawContours(blackImage, coll, 0, new Scalar(255,0,0), Core.FILLED);
        Imgproc.drawContours(blackImage, coll, 1, new Scalar(255,0,0), Core.FILLED);
        //Imgproc.fillPoly( blackImage, coll, new Scalar(0,0,255));
        blackImage.copyTo( frameIntersection);

        Imgproc.cvtColor( blackImage, blackImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList< MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours( blackImage, contours, hierarchy,  Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        System.out.println("===== contoursIntersection > number = " + contours.size());

        if (contours.size() == 1)   {
            intersec = contours.get(0);
        }
        return intersec;
```